# How to set listener in the state?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

I have a Firestore onSnapshot listener listening to changes on a document but I cant seem to understand how it works if I set it in the state like below:

```
constructor(props) {
 super(props);         
 this.fetchChatsListener = null;
}
```

and this is how I set it:

```
this.fetchChatsListener = firestore().collection('chats').doc(documentSnapshot.id).collection('messages').where('created', '>=', currenttime);
this.state.sent_message_id != '' ? this.fetchChatsListener.where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), '!=', this.state.sent_message_id) : ''
  this.fetchChatsListener.orderBy('created', 'desc')
    .onSnapshot({
      error: (e) => console.error(e),
      next: (querySnapshot_) => {

        querySnapshot_.docChanges().forEach(change => {
          this.state.dataSource.push({
            ...change.doc.data(),
            key: change.doc.id,
          });
        });

        this.setState({
          chatEntered: true,
          dataSource: this.state.dataSource,
          refreshingMessages: false,
          current_chat_id: documentSnapshot.id
        });

      },
    });
```

I call this function to unsubscribe from it:

```
unsubscribe_chats_listener() {
  this.fetchChatsListener;
  this.fetchChatsListener = null;
}
```

but unfortunately it does not unsubscribe because I keep receiving new changes.

UPDATE

when I try to unsubscribe using:

```
this.fetchChatsListener();
```

it fails with this error:

```
TypeError: this.fetchChatsListener is not a function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP code only mentions the unsubscribe function, it needs to *invoke* it.

```
unsubscribe_chats_listener() {
  this.fetchChatsListener();  // note the parens, causing invocation
  this.fetchChatsListener = null;
}
```

**EDIT**

`this.fetchChatsListener` is being initialized to a query.  Query's aren't unsubscribe functions.

```
this.fetchChatsListener = firestore().collection('chats') // a collection ref
.doc(documentSnapshot.id)  // a doc ref
.collection('messages')    // a collection ref
.where('created', '>=', currenttime);  // a query
```

`onSnapshot()` returns the unsubscribe function, so set the property there...

```
let query = firestore().collection('chats')
  .doc(documentSnapshot.id)
  .collection('messages')
  .where('created', '>=', currenttime);

  this.state.sent_message_id != '' ? query.fetchChatsListener.where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), '!=', this.state.sent_message_id) : ''
  
  query.orderBy('created', 'desc')
  this.fetchChatsListener = query.onSnapshot({  // an unsubscribe function
      error: (e) => console.error(e),
      next: (querySnapshot_) => {
      // ...
```

Comment: I did try this but it fails because thats not a function: ´TypeError: this.fetchChatsListener is not a function´

Comment: Can you post the complete line where you initialize it?  `this.fetchChatsListener = ...`.

Comment: Yes, check my updated question.

Comment: @showtime - that was a useful edit. The way to get the unsubscribe function is from the return value of onSnapshot.  See my edit

Comment: thank you! I did not read about it anywhere in the documentation. It would be nice if you can provide us with a reference where firebase has pointed that out.'

Comment: Sure: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#onsnapshot